# what is the probability of detecting departure from H0?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, approximation

The desired percentage of SiO$_2$ in a certain type of aluminous cement is 5.5. To test whether the true average percentage is 5.5 for a particular production facility, 16 independently obtained samples are analyzed. Suppose that the percentage of SiO2 in a sample is normally distributed with $\sigma$ = .3 and that $\bar{x}$ = 5.25.

If the true average percentage is $\mu$ = 5.6 and a level $\alpha$ = .01 test based on $n$ = 16 is used, what is the probability of detecting this departure from $H_0$?

---

I have been trying to figure out this problem and have found no luck with other outside resources.

At first I thought that I needed to find $\beta$(5.6), or $\Phi$($z+\frac{\mu_0-\mu'}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}}$) for when $\mu$' > $\mu_0$, but neither of these got to the correct answer of .1056.

I feel that my biggest problem is understanding what exactly "detecting this departure" means.

any help would be appreciated!

---

the question is 8.21 part b from "Probability and Statistics for Engineering and the Sciences" ninth edition by Jay L. Devore.

Comment: $\beta$ is the probability of *not* detecting the departure. Power is its complement

Comment: When I calculated 1-$\beta$(5.6), I got 0.1072263 which is close, but not the answer in the book.  this was using 2.575 as $Z_\alpha$.  using 2.58 instead gets me 0.1063054, but again is not the answer.  any advice?